# Crashing fragmented login screen after longer off-/sleep-time

Tags: boot, 16.04, nvidia, suspend, login-screen

I get a strangely fragmented GRUB- or login-screen after having my Ubuntu-machine off or in sleep-mode for more than about 30 minutes. At the last, the login screen freezes and all I can do is cold boot the system. After a reboot everything is working just fine (login as expected, no crash).

[Screenshot of the crashed login-screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPkHW.jpg).

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an Intel Xeon machine. `lspci` says I have a `NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [NVS 300]` installed whereas the "Information"-preference-pane says `Gallium 0.4 on NVA8`. Since I already had severe problems with NVIDIA graphics on another machine earlier, I don't really want to mess with the graphics drivers. At the moment I'm using the nouveau-driver.

Is there a definite or promising way to fix this?

Thanks!

---

Edit: clarifying and additional information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by installing and switching to the NVIDIA proprietary graphics card driver.

From the desktop GUI, this can be done by browsing to System-Preferences -> Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers. Here you can choose between NVIDIA binary drivers and the default Nouveau driver.

It may be the case, like I experienced earlier, that after switching the driver and rebooting the machine, you won't be able to reaccess the Ubuntu-GUI and only have the command-line to control the system. From command-line you can switch the driver back to nouveau by using `ubuntu-drivers`

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
```

which will output something like this:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:04:00.0 ==
model    : GT218 [NVS 300]
modalias : pci:v000010DEd000010D8sv000010DEsd00000862bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-304 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

With that information you would in this example reinstall the displayed nouveau drivers using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

Reboot and you're back to normal.